# Magento custom shipping rate

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Guys i need an advice on how can i achieve this shipping rule

1) Shipping cost should be at a minimum of US$25.00 or 10% of the total purchase.

Example 1:

```
Total Purchase = $25
Shipping cost = $25
Total = $50
```

Example 2:

```
Total Purchase = $500
Shipping cost = $50
Total purchase = $550.00
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve with this link for fix : $25 http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-flat-rate-shipping

And also you can achieve for 10% of total purchase with  same above link you can use to set.

Please read and try understand document to set as you need in your application.

Comment: so is it possible to set 2 different shipping fees based on subtotal?

Comment: you have to do some customization in shipping module.

Comment: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method here is good instruction to make module but in that you have to manage your requirement.